# Download custom mimetype file using WKWebView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, mime-types, wkwebview

I am rendering a web page using MKWebview. ASP page serve a downloaded file which has custom extension (xxx.hexz). But http url remain same in webview(ex: http://xx.xx.com/New/Main.asp ). I could not get this download file in webview navigation delegate. Is there any way to register custom mimetype in wkwebview to handle this?

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated) {
        print("download")
    }

     decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```